# Extjs Tree Picker, the tree scroll to top when expanding/collapse a node

Tags: tree, scroll, treeview, extjs5

Seems Extjs has a issue on tree picker, it will scroll to top when expand/collapse a node. I just put a tree picker into a form with store,and per my testing, extjs 4.2.1 and the latest 5.1.0 both have the issue.
Setting viewConfig:{preserveScrollOnRefresh:true} is not working for me. I have no access to post on extjs forum, so post here seeking help.

the tree picker located under {extjs}/examples/ux

```js
/* <debug> */
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
 enabled : true,
 paths : {
  'App' : 'app',
  'App.ux' : 'app/ux'
 }
});
/* </debug> */
Ext.application({
 name : 'App',
 requires : [ 'Ext.ux.TreePicker' ],
 launch : function() {
  Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
   layout : 'vbox',
   items : [ {
    fieldLabel : 'Tree Picker',
    xtype : 'treepicker',
              width :'60%',
    // queryMode: 'local',
    // multiSelect : true,
    displayField : 'text',
    store : Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
     root : {
      expanded : true,
      children : [ {
       text : "detention34",
                            expanded : true,
       children : [ {
        text : "detention33",
        leaf : true
       }, {
        text : "homework32",
        expanded : true,
        children : [ {
         text : "book report31",
         leaf : true
        }, {
         text : "algebra30",
         leaf : true
        } ]
       }, {
        text : "buy lottery tickets29",
        children : [ {
         text : "detention28",
         leaf : true
        }, {
         text : "homework27",
         expanded : true,
         children : [ {
          text : "book report26",
          leaf : true
         }, {
          text : "algebra25",
          leaf : true
         } ]
        }, {
         text : "buy lottery tickets24",
         leaf : true
        } ]
       } ]
      }, {
       text : "homework23",
       expanded : true,
       children : [ {
        text : "book report22",
        leaf : true
       }, {
        text : "algebra21",
                              expanded : true,
        children : [ {
         text : "detention",
         leaf : true
        }, {
         text : "homework20",
         expanded : true,
         children : [ {
          text : "book report19",
          leaf : true
         }, {
          text : "algebra18",
          leaf : true
         } ]
        }, {
         text : "buy lottery tickets17",
                                    expanded : true,
         children : [ {
          text : "detention16",
          leaf : true
         }, {
          text : "homework15",
          expanded : true,
          children : [ {
           text : "book report14",
           leaf : true
          }, {
           text : "algebra13",
           leaf : true
          } ]
         }, {
          text : "buy lottery tickets12",
                                        expanded : true,
          children : [ {
           text : "detention11",
           leaf : true
          }, {
           text : "homework10",
           expanded : true,
           children : [ {
            text : "book report9",
            leaf : true
           }, {
            text : "algebra8",
            leaf : true
           } ]
          }, {
           text : "buy lottery tickets7",
                                            expanded : true,
           children : [ {
            text : "detention6",
            leaf : true
           }, {
            text : "homework5",
            expanded : true,
            children : [ {
             text : "book report4",
             leaf : true
            }, {
             text : "algebra3",
             leaf : true
            } ]
           }, {
            text : "buy lottery tickets2",
            leaf : true
           } ]
          } ]
         } ]
        } ]
       } ]
      }, {
       text : "buy lottery tickets1",
       leaf : true
      } ]
     }
    })
   } ]
  });
 }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome to Ext JS!</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.1/resources/css/ext-all.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.1/ext-all.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
          /** 
 * A Picker field that contains a tree panel on its popup, enabling selection of tree nodes.
 */
Ext.define('Ext.ux.TreePicker', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Picker',
    xtype: 'treepicker',
    
    uses: [
        'Ext.tree.Panel'
    ],

    triggerCls: Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'form-arrow-trigger',

    config: {
        /**
         * @cfg {Ext.data.TreeStore} store
         * A tree store that the tree picker will be bound to
         */
        store: null,

        /**
         * @cfg {String} displayField
         * The field inside the model that will be used as the node's text.
         * Defaults to the default value of {@link Ext.tree.Panel}'s `displayField` configuration.
         */
        displayField: null,

        /**
         * @cfg {Array} columns
         * An optional array of columns for multi-column trees
         */
        columns: null,

        /**
         * @cfg {Boolean} selectOnTab
         * Whether the Tab key should select the currently highlighted item. Defaults to `true`.
         */
        selectOnTab: true,

        /**
         * @cfg {Number} maxPickerHeight
         * The maximum height of the tree dropdown. Defaults to 300.
         */
        maxPickerHeight: 300,

        /**
         * @cfg {Number} minPickerHeight
         * The minimum height of the tree dropdown. Defaults to 100.
         */
        minPickerHeight: 100
    },
   
    editable: false,

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;
        me.callParent(arguments);

        me.addEvents(
            /**
             * @event select
             * Fires when a tree node is selected
             * @param {Ext.ux.TreePicker} picker        This tree picker
             * @param {Ext.data.Model} record           The selected record
             */
            'select'
        );

        me.mon(me.store, {
            scope: me,
            load: me.onLoad,
            update: me.onUpdate
        });
    },

    /**
     * Creates and returns the tree panel to be used as this field's picker.
     */
    createPicker: function() {
        var me = this,
            picker = new Ext.tree.Panel({
                shrinkWrapDock: 2,
                store: me.store,
                floating: true,
                displayField: me.displayField,
                columns: me.columns,
                minHeight: me.minPickerHeight,
                maxHeight: me.maxPickerHeight,
                manageHeight: false,
                shadow: false,
                rootVisible: false,
                listeners: {
                    scope: me,
                    itemclick: me.onItemClick
                },
                viewConfig: {
                  //it's not working
                  preserveScrollOnRefresh:true,
                    listeners: {
                        scope: me,
                        render: me.onViewRender
                    }
                }
            }),
            view = picker.getView();

        if (Ext.isIE9 && Ext.isStrict) {
            // In IE9 strict mode, the tree view grows by the height of the horizontal scroll bar when the items are highlighted or unhighlighted.
            // Also when items are collapsed or expanded the height of the view is off. Forcing a repaint fixes the problem.
            view.on({
                scope: me,
                highlightitem: me.repaintPickerView,
                unhighlightitem: me.repaintPickerView,
                afteritemexpand: me.repaintPickerView,
                afteritemcollapse: me.repaintPickerView
            });
        }
        return picker;
    },
    
    onViewRender: function(view){
        view.getEl().on('keypress', this.onPickerKeypress, this);
    },

    /**
     * repaints the tree view
     */
    repaintPickerView: function() {
        var style = this.picker.getView().getEl().dom.style;

        // can't use Element.repaint because it contains a setTimeout, which results in a flicker effect
        style.display = style.display;
    },

    /**
     * Aligns the picker to the input element
     */
    alignPicker: function() {
        var me = this,
            picker;

        if (me.isExpanded) {
            picker = me.getPicker();
            if (me.matchFieldWidth) {
                // Auto the height (it will be constrained by max height)
                picker.setWidth(me.bodyEl.getWidth());
            }
            if (picker.isFloating()) {
                me.doAlign();
            }
        }
    },

    /**
     * Handles a click even on a tree node
     * @private
     * @param {Ext.tree.View} view
     * @param {Ext.data.Model} record
     * @param {HTMLElement} node
     * @param {Number} rowIndex
     * @param {Ext.EventObject} e
     */
    onItemClick: function(view, record, node, rowIndex, e) {
        this.selectItem(record);
    },

    /**
     * Handles a keypress event on the picker element
     * @private
     * @param {Ext.EventObject} e
     * @param {HTMLElement} el
     */
    onPickerKeypress: function(e, el) {
        var key = e.getKey();

        if(key === e.ENTER || (key === e.TAB && this.selectOnTab)) {
            this.selectItem(this.picker.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0]);
        }
    },

    /**
     * Changes the selection to a given record and closes the picker
     * @private
     * @param {Ext.data.Model} record
     */
    selectItem: function(record) {
        var me = this;
        me.setValue(record.getId());
        me.picker.hide();
        me.inputEl.focus();
        me.fireEvent('select', me, record)

    },

    /**
     * Runs when the picker is expanded.  Selects the appropriate tree node based on the value of the input element,
     * and focuses the picker so that keyboard navigation will work.
     * @private
     */
    onExpand: function() {
        var me = this,
            picker = me.picker,
            store = picker.store,
            value = me.value,
            node;

        
        if (value) {
            node = store.getNodeById(value);
        }
        
        if (!node) {
            node = store.getRootNode();
        }
        
        picker.selectPath(node.getPath());

        Ext.defer(function() {
            picker.getView().focus();
        }, 1);
    },

    /**
     * Sets the specified value into the field
     * @param {Mixed} value
     * @return {Ext.ux.TreePicker} this
     */
    setValue: function(value) {
        var me = this,
            record;

        me.value = value;

        if (me.store.loading) {
            // Called while the Store is loading. Ensure it is processed by the onLoad method.
            return me;
        }
            
        // try to find a record in the store that matches the value
        record = value ? me.store.getNodeById(value) : me.store.getRootNode();
        if (value === undefined) {
            record = me.store.getRootNode();
            me.value = record.getId();
        } else {
            record = me.store.getNodeById(value);
        }

        // set the raw value to the record's display field if a record was found
        me.setRawValue(record ? record.get(me.displayField) : '');

        return me;
    },
    
    getSubmitValue: function(){
        return this.value;    
    },

    /**
     * Returns the current data value of the field (the idProperty of the record)
     * @return {Number}
     */
    getValue: function() {
        return this.value;
    },

    /**
     * Handles the store's load event.
     * @private
     */
    onLoad: function() {
        var value = this.value;

        if (value) {
            this.setValue(value);
        }
    },
    
    onUpdate: function(store, rec, type, modifiedFieldNames){
        var display = this.displayField;
        
        if (type === 'edit' && modifiedFieldNames && Ext.Array.contains(modifiedFieldNames, display) && this.value === rec.getId()) {
            this.setRawValue(rec.get(display));
        }
    }

});


      </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
  <script type ="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I recently came across this issue. This is currently a logged bug: [EXTJS-16779](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?297661-Combo-Tree-keep-vertical-scroll-and-expanded-node-aligned-(with-Fiddle))

This seems to happen between during the layout cycle. I couldn't find an event to hook into (they either happened to early or too late), but this seemed to work well.

```js
/* <debug> */
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
 enabled : true,
 paths : {
  'App' : 'app',
  'App.ux' : 'app/ux'
 }
});

Ext.define('Ext.override.ux.TreePicker', {
    override: 'Ext.ux.TreePicker',

    createPicker: function() {
        var me = this,
            picker = new Ext.tree.Panel({
                shrinkWrapDock: 2,
                store: me.store,
                floating: true,
                displayField: me.displayField,
                columns: me.columns,
                minHeight: me.minPickerHeight,
                maxHeight: me.maxPickerHeight,
                manageHeight: false,
                shadow: false,
                rootVisible: false,
                listeners: {
                    scope: me,
                    itemclick: me.onItemClick
                },
                viewConfig: {
                    listeners: {
                        scope: me,
                        render: me.onViewRender,
                        // Get the current scroll before the click
                        beforeitemclick: function() {
                            var vw = picker.getView();
                            if (Ext.getVersion().major > 4)
                               picker._scrollY = vw.getScrollY();
                            else
                               picker._scrollY = vw.getEl().getScroll().top;
                        }
                    }
                },

                layout: {
                    // Set the scroll after the layout.
                    finishedLayout: function() {
                        var layoutFns = Ext.layout.container.Fit.prototype;
                        layoutFns.finishedLayout.apply(this, arguments);
          
                        if (picker._scrollY) {
                           picker.getView().getEl().dom.scrollTop 
                               = picker._scrollY;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }),
            view = picker.getView();

        if (Ext.isIE9 && Ext.isStrict) {
            // In IE9 strict mode, the tree view grows by the height of the horizontal scroll bar when the items are highlighted or unhighlighted.
            // Also when items are collapsed or expanded the height of the view is off. Forcing a repaint fixes the problem.
            view.on({
                scope: me,
                highlightitem: me.repaintPickerView,
                unhighlightitem: me.repaintPickerView,
                afteritemexpand: me.repaintPickerView,
                afteritemcollapse: me.repaintPickerView
            });
        }
        return picker;
    },
});
/* </debug> */
Ext.application({
 name : 'App',
 requires : [ 'Ext.ux.TreePicker' ],
 launch : function() {
  Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
   layout : 'vbox',
   items : [ {
    fieldLabel : 'Tree Picker',
    xtype : 'treepicker',
              width :'60%',
    // queryMode: 'local',
    // multiSelect : true,
    displayField : 'text',
    store : Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
     root : {
      expanded : true,
      children : [ {
       text : "detention34",
                            expanded : true,
       children : [ {
        text : "detention33",
        leaf : true
       }, {
        text : "homework32",
        expanded : true,
        children : [ {
         text : "book report31",
         leaf : true
        }, {
         text : "algebra30",
         leaf : true
        } ]
       }, {
        text : "buy lottery tickets29",
        children : [ {
         text : "detention28",
         leaf : true
        }, {
         text : "homework27",
         expanded : true,
         children : [ {
          text : "book report26",
          leaf : true
         }, {
          text : "algebra25",
          leaf : true
         } ]
        }, {
         text : "buy lottery tickets24",
         leaf : true
        } ]
       } ]
      }, {
       text : "homework23",
       expanded : true,
       children : [ {
        text : "book report22",
        leaf : true
       }, {
        text : "algebra21",
                              expanded : true,
        children : [ {
         text : "detention",
         leaf : true
        }, {
         text : "homework20",
         expanded : true,
         children : [ {
          text : "book report19",
          leaf : true
         }, {
          text : "algebra18",
          leaf : true
         } ]
        }, {
         text : "buy lottery tickets17",
                                    expanded : true,
         children : [ {
          text : "detention16",
          leaf : true
         }, {
          text : "homework15",
          expanded : true,
          children : [ {
           text : "book report14",
           leaf : true
          }, {
           text : "algebra13",
           leaf : true
          } ]
         }, {
          text : "buy lottery tickets12",
                                        expanded : true,
          children : [ {
           text : "detention11",
           leaf : true
          }, {
           text : "homework10",
           expanded : true,
           children : [ {
            text : "book report9",
            leaf : true
           }, {
            text : "algebra8",
            leaf : true
           } ]
          }, {
           text : "buy lottery tickets7",
                                            expanded : true,
           children : [ {
            text : "detention6",
            leaf : true
           }, {
            text : "homework5",
            expanded : true,
            children : [ {
             text : "book report4",
             leaf : true
            }, {
             text : "algebra3",
             leaf : true
            } ]
           }, {
            text : "buy lottery tickets2",
            leaf : true
           } ]
          } ]
         } ]
        } ]
       } ]
      }, {
       text : "buy lottery tickets1",
       leaf : true
      } ]
     }
    })
   } ]
  });
 }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome to Ext JS!</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.1/resources/css/ext-all.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.1/ext-all.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
          /** 
 * A Picker field that contains a tree panel on its popup, enabling selection of tree nodes.
 */
Ext.define('Ext.ux.TreePicker', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Picker',
    xtype: 'treepicker',
    
    uses: [
        'Ext.tree.Panel'
    ],

    triggerCls: Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'form-arrow-trigger',

    config: {
        /**
         * @cfg {Ext.data.TreeStore} store
         * A tree store that the tree picker will be bound to
         */
        store: null,

        /**
         * @cfg {String} displayField
         * The field inside the model that will be used as the node's text.
         * Defaults to the default value of {@link Ext.tree.Panel}'s `displayField` configuration.
         */
        displayField: null,

        /**
         * @cfg {Array} columns
         * An optional array of columns for multi-column trees
         */
        columns: null,

        /**
         * @cfg {Boolean} selectOnTab
         * Whether the Tab key should select the currently highlighted item. Defaults to `true`.
         */
        selectOnTab: true,

        /**
         * @cfg {Number} maxPickerHeight
         * The maximum height of the tree dropdown. Defaults to 300.
         */
        maxPickerHeight: 300,

        /**
         * @cfg {Number} minPickerHeight
         * The minimum height of the tree dropdown. Defaults to 100.
         */
        minPickerHeight: 100
    },
   
    editable: false,

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;
        me.callParent(arguments);

        me.addEvents(
            /**
             * @event select
             * Fires when a tree node is selected
             * @param {Ext.ux.TreePicker} picker        This tree picker
             * @param {Ext.data.Model} record           The selected record
             */
            'select'
        );

        me.mon(me.store, {
            scope: me,
            load: me.onLoad,
            update: me.onUpdate
        });
    },

    /**
     * Creates and returns the tree panel to be used as this field's picker.
     */
    createPicker: function() {
        var me = this,
            picker = new Ext.tree.Panel({
                shrinkWrapDock: 2,
                store: me.store,
                floating: true,
                displayField: me.displayField,
                columns: me.columns,
                minHeight: me.minPickerHeight,
                maxHeight: me.maxPickerHeight,
                manageHeight: false,
                shadow: false,
                rootVisible: false,
                listeners: {
                    scope: me,
                    itemclick: me.onItemClick
                },
                viewConfig: {
                  //it's not working
                  preserveScrollOnRefresh:true,
                    listeners: {
                        scope: me,
                        render: me.onViewRender
                    }
                }
            }),
            view = picker.getView();

        if (Ext.isIE9 && Ext.isStrict) {
            // In IE9 strict mode, the tree view grows by the height of the horizontal scroll bar when the items are highlighted or unhighlighted.
            // Also when items are collapsed or expanded the height of the view is off. Forcing a repaint fixes the problem.
            view.on({
                scope: me,
                highlightitem: me.repaintPickerView,
                unhighlightitem: me.repaintPickerView,
                afteritemexpand: me.repaintPickerView,
                afteritemcollapse: me.repaintPickerView
            });
        }
        return picker;
    },
    
    onViewRender: function(view){
        view.getEl().on('keypress', this.onPickerKeypress, this);
    },

    /**
     * repaints the tree view
     */
    repaintPickerView: function() {
        var style = this.picker.getView().getEl().dom.style;

        // can't use Element.repaint because it contains a setTimeout, which results in a flicker effect
        style.display = style.display;
    },

    /**
     * Aligns the picker to the input element
     */
    alignPicker: function() {
        var me = this,
            picker;

        if (me.isExpanded) {
            picker = me.getPicker();
            if (me.matchFieldWidth) {
                // Auto the height (it will be constrained by max height)
                picker.setWidth(me.bodyEl.getWidth());
            }
            if (picker.isFloating()) {
                me.doAlign();
            }
        }
    },

    /**
     * Handles a click even on a tree node
     * @private
     * @param {Ext.tree.View} view
     * @param {Ext.data.Model} record
     * @param {HTMLElement} node
     * @param {Number} rowIndex
     * @param {Ext.EventObject} e
     */
    onItemClick: function(view, record, node, rowIndex, e) {
        this.selectItem(record);
    },

    /**
     * Handles a keypress event on the picker element
     * @private
     * @param {Ext.EventObject} e
     * @param {HTMLElement} el
     */
    onPickerKeypress: function(e, el) {
        var key = e.getKey();

        if(key === e.ENTER || (key === e.TAB && this.selectOnTab)) {
            this.selectItem(this.picker.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0]);
        }
    },

    /**
     * Changes the selection to a given record and closes the picker
     * @private
     * @param {Ext.data.Model} record
     */
    selectItem: function(record) {
        var me = this;
        me.setValue(record.getId());
        me.picker.hide();
        me.inputEl.focus();
        me.fireEvent('select', me, record)

    },

    /**
     * Runs when the picker is expanded.  Selects the appropriate tree node based on the value of the input element,
     * and focuses the picker so that keyboard navigation will work.
     * @private
     */
    onExpand: function() {
        var me = this,
            picker = me.picker,
            store = picker.store,
            value = me.value,
            node;

        
        if (value) {
            node = store.getNodeById(value);
        }
        
        if (!node) {
            node = store.getRootNode();
        }
        
        picker.selectPath(node.getPath());

        Ext.defer(function() {
            picker.getView().focus();
        }, 1);
    },

    /**
     * Sets the specified value into the field
     * @param {Mixed} value
     * @return {Ext.ux.TreePicker} this
     */
    setValue: function(value) {
        var me = this,
            record;

        me.value = value;

        if (me.store.loading) {
            // Called while the Store is loading. Ensure it is processed by the onLoad method.
            return me;
        }
            
        // try to find a record in the store that matches the value
        record = value ? me.store.getNodeById(value) : me.store.getRootNode();
        if (value === undefined) {
            record = me.store.getRootNode();
            me.value = record.getId();
        } else {
            record = me.store.getNodeById(value);
        }

        // set the raw value to the record's display field if a record was found
        me.setRawValue(record ? record.get(me.displayField) : '');

        return me;
    },
    
    getSubmitValue: function(){
        return this.value;    
    },

    /**
     * Returns the current data value of the field (the idProperty of the record)
     * @return {Number}
     */
    getValue: function() {
        return this.value;
    },

    /**
     * Handles the store's load event.
     * @private
     */
    onLoad: function() {
        var value = this.value;

        if (value) {
            this.setValue(value);
        }
    },
    
    onUpdate: function(store, rec, type, modifiedFieldNames){
        var display = this.displayField;
        
        if (type === 'edit' && modifiedFieldNames && Ext.Array.contains(modifiedFieldNames, display) && this.value === rec.getId()) {
            this.setRawValue(rec.get(display));
        }
    }

});


      </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

    </head>
    <body></body>
  <script type ="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: can you highlight what was the fix actually?

Comment: I faced same issue but to solve it, I had to remember the y position in beforeitemexpand listener instead of beforeitemclick

Answer (score 1):

Try to add listener for a treeview:

```
afteritemexpand: function (node, index, item, eOpts) {
    item.scrollIntoView(me.tree.view.el, false, true);
}
```

It's focus on expanded element.

Answer (score 0):

do not set maxHeight,it will work